# External drive put inside computer as 2nd drive, will it keep files already on it in tact, or will it auto format it?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

If I take my external drive and put it inside my computer as a second drive, if it already has stuff on it, like music, files, ect.. will it keep them intact or format it automatically?

Answer (score 4):

All your stuff will still be there.  You do not need to reformat.

Comment: Thx for the quick response. Prongs on my usb external drive broke so I was just going to put it inside my computer as a second drive, hoping all my music would still be there. THX

Answer (score 0):

It depends what software you have running on your computer.  If you're just running an operating system, then no, **I don't know of any common operating system that will automagically format your hard drive when you start up your computer**.

That being said, if you did happen to have [Darik's Boot & Nuke (DBAN)](http://www.dban.org/) on a USB flash drive that you booted from, or it was installed on a hard drive, than indeed everything would be gone.  The point is, *you* should know if the drive will be erased or not, because it depends what *you* have on the computer.  Obviously the DBAN case is less likely to happen, but it's not unheard of to see viruses corrupting/infecting files on external drives, or ones whose payload is simply to format all the drives in your computer.